# Gatling: Load Testing for dummies

Tags: load-testing, gatling

I had been assigned to do a Research and Implement Gatling tool in our company.

Anyone who can share there experience about the tool?

Comment: http://gatling.io/docs/2.2/quickstart/

Comment: Gatling is already implemented

Comment: @dzieciou oh sorry for the confusion, I mean implement -- to use it in our company.

Comment: Did you tried google? Do you want us to google it for you?

Comment: This is way too broad a question for the Q&A format - "If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much." http://sqa.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 1):

I think this [link](http://automationrhapsody.com/performance-testing-with-gatling/) should be a nice start. It has a step by step description of how to use Gatling and also pictorial representation helps a lot in understanding.

This link also would help you in getting [acquainted](http://www.baeldung.com/introduction-to-gatling) with Gatling.